# add_food() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, methods, arguments

Below is my code:

```
class Food(object):

    def __init__(self,name,calories,foodID):
    self.__name = name
    self.__calories = calories
    self.__foodID = foodID

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({} cal)".format(self.__name,self.__calories,self.__foodID)      

    #ACCESSOR VARIABLE

    def get_foodID(self):
        return self.__foodID

    def get_foodCalories(self):
        return self.__calories

class Meal(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__food_list = []

    def add_food(food):
        self.__food_list.append(food)

chs = Food("cheese", 80, 12345)

meal = Meal()
meal.add_food(chs)
```

The Meal class should have only one property; a list. The add_food() method should add the Food argument to the Meal. Its telling me I am giving 2 arguments but I dont see where

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `self` in your `add_food` method

change this:

```
def add_food(food):
```

to this

```
def add_food(self, food):
```